# Improving performance of slow query - Potentially by disabling change tracking

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, change-tracking, entity-framework-6

I have a Linq query on a DbSet that hits a table and grabs 65k rows. The query takes about 3 minutes, to me that seems like obviously too much. Although I don't have a line of comparison but I'm certain this can be improved. I'm relative new to EF and Linq so I suspect I may also be structuring my query in a way that is a big "NO".

I read that change tracking is where EF spends most of it's time, and that is enabled on the entity in question so perhaps I should turn that off (if so, how)?

Here's the code:

```
ReportTarget reportTarget = repository.GetById(reportTargetId);
if (reportTarget != null)
{
    ReportsBundle targetBundle = reportTarget.SavedReportsBundles.SingleOrDefault(rb => rb.ReportsBundleId == target.ReportsBundleId);
    if (targetBundle != null)
    {
    }
}
```

This next line takes 3 Minutes to execute (65k records):

```
IPoint[] pointsData = targetBundle.ReportEntries
                          .Where(e => ... a few conditions )
                          .Select((entry, i) => new
                              {
                                 rowID = entry.EntryId,
                                 x = entry.Profit,
                                 y = i,
                                 weight = target.HiddenPoints.Contains(entry.EntryId) ? 0 : 1,
                                 group = 0
                              }.ActLike<IPoint>())
                          .ToArray();
```

**Note:** ActLike() is from [Impromptu Interface](https://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/) library that uses the .NET DLR to make dynamic proxies of objects that implement an interface on the fly. I doubt this is the bottle neck.

How can I optimize performance for this particular DbSet (`TradesReportEntries`) as I'll be querying this table for large data sets (`IPoint[]`s) often

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it looks like you're loading an entity object then querying navigation properties.  When this occurs, EF loads all related entities *FIRST* (via lazy loading), then your query is performed on the entire collection.  This may be why you're having performance issues.

Try querying against the collection by using the following:

```
context.Entry(targetBundle)
    .Collection(p => p.TradesReportEntries)
    .Query()
    .Where( e => <your filter here> )
    .Select( <your projection here> )
```

This allows you to specify a filter in addition to the behind-the-curtain filter that handles loading the nav property by default.  Let us know how that works out.